# Can I have scripts outside my python exe?

Tags: python, pygtk, py2exe

I'm new to Python and starting to learn it.  However I have one query, which I'd like to know for the future.

Once I've made a python program and produced an exe via py2exe, is it then possible to execute python scripts outside of the exe or do I have to look at plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is entirely possible. It's a standard Python interpreter. You'll need to put the directory in `sys.path` so that the filesystem importer will pick it up. And then for runtime imports generally using the `__import__` function will be the easiest way.

A Google search for "py2exe runtime import" provides early in the results one example of it: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t330613-py2exe-excluding-a-module-and-import-it-during-runtime-how.html